# JPA Repository search by custom field

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, jpa, path-variables

I am trying to get a list of the objects with the same field.

I have a model named Song, with the fields: name, genre, artist and id.

I read online about how to implement the method in the repository and i added it like this:

```
@Repository public interface ISongRepository extends JpaRepository<Song, Long>{

    @Query("SELECT s.name FROM Song s WHERE s.genre = ?1")
    Song findByGenre(String genre); 
}
```

Now i want to retrieve the objects with an endpoint that i create in the controller. But i can't find online how i need to correctly write this method.

I tried to use the same format as my get by id but that doesn't work, is there a different format when it comes to custom methods?

Code of my get by id:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity getSongById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Optional<Song> song = songRepository.findById(id);

    if(song.isEmpty()) {
      return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(song);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(song.get());
}
```

Code of my method to retrieve the output of the custom method:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/genre/{genre}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity getSongByGenre(@PathVariable("genre") String songGenre){
        List<Song> song = song.(songRepository.findByGenre(songGenre));

        if(song.isEmpty()){
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(song);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(song.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: "*`List<Song> song = song.(songRepository.findByGenre(songGenre));`*" - That should result in a compilation errorr. `findByGenere` returns a `Song`, not a `List<Song>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `@Param` at `ISongRepository` and change the return type `findByGenre` method to `List<Song>`

, Also make sure that you retrieve the `id` or `genre` from the rest controllers

```
@Repository public interface ISongRepository extends JpaRepository<Song, Long>{

    @Query("SELECT s FROM Song s WHERE s.genre =:genre")
    List<Song> findByGenre(@Param("genre") String genre); 
}
```

Comment: You may want to mention that you also changed the return type from `Song` to `List<Song>` and that you use named parameters instead of anonymous parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I get the right results now.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the method to this in the Controller:

```
 @GetMapping("/genre/{genre}")
 public ResponseEntity getAllSongsGenre(@PathVariable("genre") String genre){
         List<Song> song;
         if(genre != null){
             song = songRepository.findByGenre(genre);
             if(song.isEmpty()){
                 return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(song);
             }
             return ResponseEntity.ok(song);
         }
         song = songRepository.findAll();
 
         return ResponseEntity.ok(song);
     }
```

And in the JPARepository to this:

```
 List<Song> findByGenre(String genre);
```

The output is like this (In Postman):

```
{
    "songName": "Someday",
    "songArtist": "Kygo",
    "songGenre": "House",
    "songId": 1
}
```